# Adding variables from a text file to be used in URL path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, url, cmd

I read several threads on similar issues but so far unable to find specific solution. I need to execute a batch file on a number of computers to repair a corrupted management agent. Because the agent is corrupted I cannot use the management system to resolve the issue and I have a tested solution that uses `WMIC`.

I have a text file containing a list of computer names, is it possible to **pull the computer names from the text file and use in the below batch file**?

```
@echo off

set compname=%computername%

IF EXIST "\\%compname%\C$\Install\" GOTO CopyFile

mkdir "\\%compname%\C$\Install\"

:CopyFile

copy "\\shareserver\sharefolder\AgentRepair.cmd" "\\%compname%\C$\Install\"

wmic /NODE:%compname% /USER:domain\username /PASSWORD:password process call create "c:\Install\AgentRepair.cmd" 

exit
```

Comment: The functionality you're looking for is already built into the `WMIC` command, `WMIC /NODE:@filename.ext /USER:domain\username /PASSWORD:password …`. Note: Use doublequotes around those values if they contain problematic characters, _(noting that `-` and `/` will also need protecting as they are used to define the parameters themselves)_.

Comment: Thank you was unable to get this to work, possible syntax error. If text filename was pcnames.txt would this be  WMIC /NODE:@pcnames.txt /USER:domain\username /PASSWORD:password...

Comment: LostInRelaxation, what I provided was documented command syntax.

Comment: My apologies, I can run the command manually at a command prompt but when executed in a batch file I still seem to be running into an issue. The computer names are being pulled from the text file as the directory is created and the batch file copied to the computers in the text file but WMIC command is not successfully calling the batch file. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do (
 mkdir "\\%%a\C$\Install\" 2>nul >nul
 copy "\\shareserver\sharefolder\AgentRepair.cmd" "\\%%a\C$\Install\"
 wmic /NODE:%%a /USER:domain\username /PASSWORD:password process call create "c:\Install\AgentRepair.cmd" 
)
pause
exit
```

should work - with one name to a line in *filename*

`%%a` simply receives each line in turn from the file. Note that the `2>nul` redirects error messages generated by a command to *nowhere* - the `mkdir / md` command will generate an error message if the directory already exists.

Bug-fix : each `%%a` must be the same case. I posted the `wmic` command with `%%A` (balancing keyboard on knees). This should fix the problem. Changing `@echo off` to `@echo on` would produce a command-by-command trace of operation.

Comment: Thank you. Testing but still unable to get script to read names from text file. Before posting was attempting similar solution but syntax was incorrect, yours does appear correct but not executing.

Comment: My apologies, your suggestion works, the computer names are being pulled from the text file as the directory is created and the batch file is copied to the computers listed in the text file but WMIC command is not successfully calling the batch file.
I can run the command manually at a command prompt but when executed in a batch file I still seem to be running into an issue. The original simple test batch file does however complete the only difference being the /NODE parameter. Still working on the problem. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to let PowerShell do the invocation work.

=== AgentRepair.ps1

```
$InstDir = 'C:\Install'
if (-not Test-Path -Path $InstDir) { mkdir $InstDir }
Copy-Item '\\shareserver\sharefolder\AgentRepair.cmd' $InstDir
& $InstDir\AgentRepair.cmd
```

=== Run it

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content .\computernames.txt) -FilePath .\AgentRepair.ps1
```

=== Or, from a cmd.exe shell

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content .\computernames.txt) -FilePath .\AgentRepair.ps1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Getting "execution of scripts is disabled on this system" when attempting to run.set-executionpolicy unrestricted

Comment: You must "Run as administrator" in order to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy`. If you are in a corporate environment, there may be a group policy that prevents this. Getting all of the machines setup may be some work, but once it is done some things become much easier.